# Program type already present: okhttp3.Authenticator$1

Tags: android, instamojo, kite

we use kiteconnect.jar file in lib folder for socket connection. Now i m integrating Instamojo payment gateway in application but got this error while run application
**Program type already present: okhttp3.Authenticator$1
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: okhttp3.Authenticator$1, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}**

after extracting kiteconnect.jar file found the okhttp3 interface in that.
now i don't know how to handle this.
Please help me out

Comment: Same problem here, and I didn't find out what's happening yet :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51924812/6052942 check this ans.. this is working in  my project..

Answer (score 0):

To resolve dependency conflicts, add a configuration.

```
configurations {

all*.exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'

 }
```

Answer (score -1):

With Android Studio "3.1.3", It looks like you don't need to  explicitly add okhttp3 to your project's gradle anymore. Try to remove all okhttp3 lines from your build.gradle. Then sync your project to see if everything works fine.

```html
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.0.0'
```

It works for me. Here is my Android Studio version details :
Android Studio 3.1.3
Build #AI-173.4819257, built on June 4, 2018 
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o